# How to linearize a base-10 exponential function

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, graphing-functions, linearization

I have a base-10 exponential function with the equation:

$$y = 0.000346 \cdot 10^{0.00676x} + 0.148$$

I am trying to linearize this equation but unable to do so. I tried taking $\log(y)$ in the $y$-axis and $\log(x)$ in the $x$-axis but I am never getting a straight line. In fact, taking $\log(y)$ gives me negative $y$-values. Any help would be appreciated.

I have attached an imgur link to my graph below since I am unable to embed it here. Thank you so much.

[image: imgur link to graph]

Comment: Hint: move the constant term first, then take logarithms on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=A\cdot 10^{Bx}+C$$

$$y-C=A\cdot 10^{Bx}$$

if $A>0$, then $y-C$ should be positive, hence we can take logarithm

$$\log_{10}(y-C)=\log A + Bx $$

Now can you see what should $Y$ be for the linearized model?